# GeoJSON from API won't show with react-leaflet

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ajax, leaflet, react-leaflet

I'm doing an Ajax API call to receive a GeoJSON containing multiple polygons. This all works fine and they get set as "data" for my `<GeoJSON />`. My Map Component looks something like this:

```
const [features, setFeatures] = useState([]);

let handleFeatureAPI = () => {
        axios
        .get("/api/polygons/")
        .then((res) => setFeatures(res.data))
        .catch((err) => console.log(err));
    }

useEffect(()=>{  // Placeholder
        handleFeatureAPI()
    }, [])

return (

....
    <MapContainer center={lat_lon} zoom={11} scrollWheelZoom={true} zoomControl={false} onClick={handleDrawerClose}>
         <TileLayer attribution='&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
                    url="https://{s}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/light_all/{z}/{x}/{y}{r}.png"
                />
         {features && (<GeoJSON style={polystyle} data={features} onEachFeature={onEachFeature} />)}                
    </MapContainer>
```

I know that I have to "reload" the `<GeoJSON/>` component and tried to only display it if it's available with `{features && (<GeoJSON/>)}` but this doesn't work.
What did I do wrong?

Comment: `{features && ..}` will make sense only if features is `null` in the first place not `[]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did solve it myself, but attention: It might still not be best practice.

Combination of useEffect and useRef solved the issue and only loads the `<GeoJSON />` once.

```
const [features, setFeatures] = useState([]);

const fetchData = () => {
        setLoading(true);
        axios.get("/api/polygons/")
            .then((res) => {
                setLoading(false);
                setFeatures(res.data);
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                setLoading(true);
                console.log(err)
            });

    };





const geoJsonLayerRef = useRef(null);

useEffect(() => { fetchData() }, []);


useEffect(() => {
        const layer = geoJsonLayerRef.current;
        if (layer) {
            console.log("redrawing")
            layer.clearLayers().addData(features);
        }
    }, [features]);


return ( ....

<MapContainer center={city_lat_lon} zoom={11} scrollWheelZoom={true} zoomControl={false} onClick={handleDrawerClose}>
                <TileLayer
                    attribution='&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
                    url="https://{s}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/light_all/{z}/{x}/{y}{r}.png"
                />
                <GeoJSON ref={geoJsonLayerRef} style={polystyle} data={features} onEachFeature={onEachFeature} />
            </MapContainer> .....)
```